# Cannot access MYSQL database on AWS lightsail

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am working on a simple application using the LAMP stack using AWS/Lightsail. It worked once, but I rebooted the instance and it stopped working. The data was not available. I suspected issue with MySQL. Below is what I tried. Can anyone suggest any solution for this?

```
bitnami@ip-123-45-67-89:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/bitnami/mysql
/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)


bitnami@ip-123-45-67-89:~$  sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
Cannot find any running daemon to contact. If it is running, make sure you are pointing to
 the right pid file (/var/run/gonit.pid)
   
bitnami@ip-123-45-67-89:~$ ps aux | grep mysql
mysql      607  0.0  6.0 1254660 29812 ?       Ssl  04:11   0:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld
bitnami   3338  0.0  0.1   6076   824 pts/0    S+   14:27   0:00 grep mysql
   
bitnami@ip-123-45-67-89:~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
Cannot find any running daemon to contact. If it is running, make sure you are pointing to
 the right pid file (/var/run/gonit.pid)

bitnami@ip-123-45-67-89:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            233M     0  233M   0% /dev
tmpfs            49M  2.8M   46M   6% /run
/dev/xvda1       20G  9.5G  9.2G  51% /
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           242M     0  242M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda15     124M  262K  124M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs            49M     0   49M   0% /run/user/1000

bitnami@ip-123-45-67-89:~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop mysql
Stopped mysql

bitnami@ip-123-45-67-89:~$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start mysql
Failed to start mysql: Failed to start mysql

bitnami@ip-123-45-67-89:~$ ps aux | grep mysql
mysql      607  0.0  3.8 1254660 18912 ?       Ssl  04:11   0:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld
bitnami   3560  0.0  0.1   6076   884 pts/0    S+   14:39   0:00 grep mysql
```

Comment: Looks like you probably have two mysql versions installed. One from your OS (eg ubuntu or Amazon Linux) and one from bitnami. You can control the OS installed one with `systemctl`.

Comment: Hi; No, I have only one instance (of mariadb) and thanks I am now using systemctl to start and stop. But that didn't help.